# "Unable to Download App" on iOS 7.1.1

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, iphone

I am not able to download any app from the App Store on my iPhone 5 which is running iOS 7.1.1.

I have been getting the following error since last week when attempting to download an app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you log into the Store via iTunes on a computer?

Comment: IMO not a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102935/cant-install-apps-from-app-store-on-iphone-with-ios-7 as the error message is different—could indicate other reason for error

Comment: @patrix Yes I can.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Yes may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, I could fix my issue.

I had to change my DNS to 8.8.8.8. 
My internet used to work before this but after changing my DNS now I am able to download apps from App Store.

But I tell I haven't changed any setting on my iPad 2 running iOS 6 still every thing works including App Store downloads. I think this issue is with iPhone 5 or definitely iOS 7.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be a problem with the AppleID.
A friend of mine had this problem that all of the devices registered to his account would not be able to download apps (even when another Apple ID is entered). Only help was to contact AppleCare (you can do that via the support tab on the apple website)

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the AppleID as I have been using the same AppleID since 1 year and I have not faced any issue as this one till last week.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart the device.
If this doesn't help, make a soft reset (you won't lose data). To make a soft reset, press the on/off button at the top and the home button until the apple icon appears (Ignore the "Slide to power off") button if it appears.
If this doesn't help, I would go to the [Genius Bar](https://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. But I have tried all you just mentioned. I have even restored my iPhone still the issue remains.

Comment: @Amol Habe you restored it to a backup or have you restored it as a new iPhone?

Comment: Actually I have tried both. Earlier I restored as new iPhone then I found that it did not rectify my issue so I have restored to backup.

Comment: @Amol did you go to the Genius Bar?

Comment: No. One of my friends helped me.

Comment: @Amol did he solve your problem? If not, I'd recommend to go to the Genius Bar (they are experts in the apple devices area)

Comment: Yes he did. Now I am able to download apps.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting same error though i can access the net and wacth videos online, infact the speed i great ranging 5mbps up,. i tried changing my dns to 4.2.2.2 and it worked right away.

Comment: You shouldn't use `4.2.2.2` for DNS unless you're a Level 3 customer. See: http://www.tummy.com/articles/famous-dns-server/

Answer (score -4):

It is not a DNS issue. U should change the date to previous dates than ur current one and ur application will install normally. I don't know why, could be a buy in IOS

Comment: Right now your answer is flagged as "low-quality", add some meat to it to prevent deletion.